# Slow performance of temp table variables

Tags: performance, temp-tables, sql-server-2017

I've always operated under the assumptions that for small to medium data sets, I would use temp table variables and once the data sets get large (relatively - and I know this is somewhat subjective), I would move to #temp tables.

I have some code that returns 159 rows very quickly - 0.00 ms.  I see 159 rows and assume temp table variables would be fine.  However, When I insert into temp table variable, the code spins for 10 minutes.  When I switch to #temp table, boom - back to 0.00 seconds.

Can someone tell me why this would occur or something I can do to figure this out?

The environment is SQL Server 2017 Enterprise, plenty of memory and disk space.

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2017
DECLARE @Month INT = NULL

DECLARE @TempTableVariable TABLE
(
    Test BIGINT

)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempdb.dbo.#TempTableTest

CREATE TABLE #TempTableTest (Test BIGINT)


--INSERT INTO @TempTableVariable

INSERT INTO #TempTableTest

SELECT 
  idfHumanCase 
FROM dbo.tlbHumanCase
WHERE YEAR(COALESCE(datOnSetDate, datFinalDiagnosisDate, datTentativeDiagnosisDate, datEnteredDate)) = @Year
AND (MONTH(COALESCE(datOnSetDate, datFinalDiagnosisDate, datTentativeDiagnosisDate, datEnteredDate)) = @Month OR @Month IS NULL)
AND LegacyCaseID IN
(
SELECT LegacyCaseID
FROM dbo.tlbHumanCase 
WHERE YEAR(COALESCE(datOnSetDate, datFinalDiagnosisDate, datTentativeDiagnosisDate, datEnteredDate)) = @Year
AND (MONTH(COALESCE(datOnSetDate, datFinalDiagnosisDate, datTentativeDiagnosisDate, datEnteredDate)) = @Month OR @Month IS NULL)

GROUP BY LegacyCaseID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)

SELECT * FROM #TempTableTest

--SELECT * FROM @TempTableVariable
```

Comment: Did you check the execution plan? Did you check sys.dm_exec_requests to see what the query is waiting on for 10 minutes? Is it possible for example that your select from `tlbHumanCase` was blocked?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The database I'm on is not accessible to anyone but me.  The select query returns instantly.  The insert runs fine on the temp table, but is extremely slow when inserting to a temp table variable.  A colleague suggested (and implemented) putting an index on the LegacyCaseID field (an nvarchar field).  This made all the difference but now I'm left wondering why it would be needed for a temp table variable insert but not for a temp table.

Comment: For future reference, blocking can happen even if there is no other _person_ involved. I'm also rather skeptical that an index on either a #temp table or a table variable (there's no such thing as a temp table variable, so it's unclear to me which one you're talking about there) could change the runtime from 10 minutes to nothing.

Comment: Thanks again for your interest.  The performance improved when I put an index on tlbHumanCase (the table I read from).  This is thoroughly confusing.  As I tried to explain above, the select returns quickly.  The performance difference is on the insert.  I run the query with just the select - no insert.  It returns 159 rows instantly.  I insert to #temp table.  Instant.  Insert to @TempTableVariable. Horribly slow.  until I put an index on the LegacyCaseID field of tlbHumanCase table.  tlbHumanCase is the main table I read from in building my result set.

Comment: And did you check sys.dm_exec_requests, like I suggested before, to see what the query is waiting on when it's "horribly slow"? Did you look at the execution plans yet? SQL Server isn't keeping secrets from you, you just have to look.